# Problem with the user of ubuntu

Tags: 20.04, root, users

I faced a strange problem in ubuntu. I shutdown my laptop as usual and went to take my exam. But when I returned and opened my laptop, my username was lost from laptop and ubuntu prompted me to make user again.. why this happened ?

Comment: So many possibilities. OS corruption due to bad or failing hard drive is one of the most common.

Comment: All the installed softwares are intact. Only user is lost and files associated with that user are lost

Comment: Is there a backup of the home directory? Could someone play a prank? Is the the school's computer, and were you removed, because you 'passed the exam and should no longer need it'?

Comment: Don't think so.. but today I have tried to change the shell with zsh but later on I unsinstalled zsh. Does it have something to do with user ?

Comment: Yes, that is possible. Did you restore the configuration for bash (for your user ID)?

Comment: Actually I ran some command and I got bored so without doing anything I uninstalled zsh.
But one interesting thing is.. when i try to create new user with same name as before, It says this user is already taken.. But that user is not shown when I try to login

Comment: It is strange that also the home directory disappeared. Is it in your home computer or in some server? Are you sure that it disappeared, maybe it is still there, but with a different name. Did you check the content of `/home` and the content of `/etc/group` ?

Comment: So zsh was the main problem..

Comment: So i got the problem.. I changed shell to zsh but later i deleted zsh.. so now it says like no such file usr/bin/zsh

Comment: What happens after you re-install zsh? You can have several shells installed. Then you can setup your user to use one of the shells.

Comment: I did it. Thank you for your time :)